# vapply and matrix; problem returning class

Tags: r, class, matrix

Is there any workaround solution for the following problem?

```
> bb = list(x=matrix(0,0,0))
> bb = list(x=matrix(0,0,0), y=numeric(0))
> vapply(bb, class, character(1))
Error in vapply(bb, class, character(1)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The first `list` element returns two values for `class` - `matrix` and `array`.  So we may need to subset by indexing with `[1]` (using a lambda/anonymous function) as we specify that the length is 1 and the return value type as `character` with `character(1)`

```
vapply(bb, function(x) class(x)[1], character(1))
#      x         y 
# "matrix" "numeric"
```

If we need both values, one option is `paste` them together

```
vapply(bb, function(x) toString(class(x)), character(1))
#             x               y 
#"matrix, array"       "numeric"
```

---

Or append `NA` at the end and extract the first two elements, while specifying the `character(2)`

```
vapply(bb, function(x) c(class(x), NA_character_)[1:2], character(2))
#.      x        y        
#[1,] "matrix" "numeric"
#[2,] "array"  NA
```

---

It can be easily found up with

```
lapply(bb, class)
#$x
#[1] "matrix" "array" 

#$y
#[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: The first solution is what I look for but it needs extra function. I hate when R assigns more than one class to an object. It makes old codes crash.